# Laravel JWT Auth get user on Login

Tags: php, laravel-5, jwt

Is it possible with https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth 
to get the `current user`? Because right now I can only generate a token (when a user sign in).

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    try {
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

Comment: You cant put the username inside the jwt

Comment: Okay interesting. Could you give an example?

Comment: I have never worked with laravel but it is a basic of the JWT. Go check some information about it. You will see that you can store anything you want inside a JWT. Basically you store the username and the role. https://jwt.io/

Comment: Yes, but how do I get the username and the role that's my question :)

Comment: Already did some research but can't find a solution.

Comment: Turns out I can just do `Auth::user();`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can get logged user data.

```
$credentials = $request->only('code', 'password', 'mobile');
try {
    // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
    if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
    }
} catch (JWTException $e) {
    // something went wrong
    return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
}

$currentUser = Auth::user();
print_r($currentUser);exit;
```

Answer (score 31):

You don't need `Auth::user();`

You can use the `toUser` method of `JWTAuth`. Just pass the token as parameter and you will get back the user info:

```
$user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);

return response()->json(compact('token', 'user'));
```

For more info, this is the toUser method:

```
/**
 * Find a user using the user identifier in the subject claim.
 *
 * @param bool|string $token
 *
 * @return mixed
 */

public function toUser($token = false)
{
    $payload = $this->getPayload($token);

    if (! $user = $this->user->getBy($this->identifier, $payload['sub'])) {
        return false;
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me but it complained that "toUser" is not a static function, thus, I needed to call it like this `$this->jwtauth->toUser($token);`

Comment: is it just me, or are the JWTauth docs really unhelpfull? ? for eg I can't find any reference to toUser

Comment: update: toUser is from the old version ! thats why its not in the docs duh. use $user = auth()->user();

Answer (score 18):

You can also use `JWTAuth::user()` method.

The `user()` method call is returned in the `toUser()` method, which itself is an alias for `authenticate()` method which authenticates a user via a token. If the user is already authenticated, there is no need to authenticate them again (which `toUser()` does), instead `user()` method can be used to get the authenticated user.

```
// $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials) was successful...

$user = JWTAuth::user();

return response()->json(compact('token', 'user'));
```

Comment: this works !, just a question, how can i send only some fields of my user data?

Comment: @realtebo Well, for example, define a new map with the values you want and return it as part of the JSON response (e.g. `response()->json(compact('myMap'))`)

Answer (score 3):

It works fine for me (laravel 5.7)
U must post token to me function and will return user
    use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;

```
public function me(Request $request)
{
    $user = JWTAuth::user();
    if (count((array)$user) > 0) {
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'user' => $user]);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['status' => 'fail'], 401);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this (it works fine with laravel 5.6,5.7):

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;

// code to generate token for user with email testuser@gmail.com
$user=User::where('email','=','testuser@gmail.com')->first();

if (!$userToken=JWTAuth::fromUser($user)) {
   return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
}

return response()->json(compact('userToken'));
```

Answer (score 2):

just need to return inside the specified route middleware 
The route that you defined api route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function () {
    Route::post('/user', function (Request $request) {
        try {
            $user = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user();
            return $user;
        } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\UserNotDefinedException $e) {
            return '$user';
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current user related to token using :

```
$user = JWTAuth::setToken($token)->toUser();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 7.2 if none of the above works use like this to retrive the user:

```
$credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

if (! $token = auth('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
}  
    
$user = auth('api')->user();
    
dd($user);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for who are all struggle validate the user and token and then guard

Problems that i face

Jwt does not return any user even i  put currect token

return null

```
 $user = JWTAuth::user(); //getting null
```

return false

```
 $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
```

return false

```
auth()->user()
```

Solution to check
Before Going to solution middleware  and your route guard is matter so keep in mind

Guard setting config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'website_admin' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'website_admin',
    ],
  ]
```

Provider

```
'providers' => [
      'super_admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Website_super_admin_auth::class,
        ],
]
```

Middleware (must)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use JWTAuth;
use Exception;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\BaseMiddleware;

class JwtMiddleware extends BaseMiddleware
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {
            $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException){
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Token is Invalid']);
            }else if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException){
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Token is Expired']);
            }else{
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Authorization Token not found']);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Route(should specify middleware with guard)

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'super_ad',  'middleware' => ['jwt.verify','auth:super_admin']], function()
{
 Route::get('/test', function (){
    // $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate(); <-------check user here
 
    $user=auth()->user();
      // return $user;
});
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
    return response()->json([$token, $user]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = JWTAuth::setToken($token)->toUser();

Auth::login($user, $remember = true);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
  public function user(Request $request){ 
    /// get user details from token
     $user = JWTAuth::toUser($this->bearerToken($request));
   // get payloads in the token
   $payload = JWTAuth::getPayload($this->bearerToken($request));
   }


public function bearerToken($request)
{
   $header = $request->header('Authorization', '');
   if (Str::startsWith($header, 'Bearer ')) {
            return Str::substr($header, 7);
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you provide an answer it's better to provide some explanation to clear your answer.