# Not working API route in laravel 5.6 with Postman

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I have a problem to test the passport in laravel, when testo in postman gives me an error.

```
"message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "/data/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
    "line": 179,
```

routes/api.php

```
Route::group([
    'prefix'        => 'api',
    'middleware'    => ['auth.api']
], function () {
    Route::post('details', 'API\UserController@details');
});
```

UserController.php

```
    public function details()
{
    dd("Ijdsijds");
    $user = Auth::user();
    return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this->successStatus);
}
```

kernel.php

```
   protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            'cors' => [
                \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
            ]
        ],
    ];
```

VerifyCRFSToken.php

```
protected $except = [
        //'authenticate'
        '/api/*'
    ];
```

Where am I going wrong? The route is listed in route: list

Comment: What is the route you are sending to with your postman?

Comment: you have placed a middleware `'middleware'    => ['auth.api']`, what does that do? Are you sending along any API key (for example) with the request?

Comment: You shouldnt really use dd command with postman it is obly designed for browsers. Just return a json or string. Api prefix isnt needed when writing routes on api.php its already set. This might be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `'prefix' => 'api'`.
Because '/api' add in the url by-default
if you not want '/api' in url remove `'prefix' => 'api'` from `RouteServiceProvider` here RouteServiceProvider file code:

```
$this->routes(function () {
        Route::middleware('api')
            ->prefix('api')
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `routes/api.php` which is stateless so you will not get any session value (here `Auth`).

To get value Either use `Passport` [Helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746078/get-user-data-using-access-token-in-laravel-passport-client-app)

or Use [JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869129/laravel-jwt-auth-get-user-on-login)

Comment: I am already using the passport, I am testing the api via postman and it returns me this error, I already tried everything here